# Access frontend size growing over 1.9Gb while connected to Sharepoint 365

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I have a ms-access frontend for stock count connected to sharepoint 365. Problem is it has swelled to 1.9GB and with every passing stock count, it is increasing size.
If I do not cache sharepoint list, reports will take forever to generate.

I am concerned whether ms-access 2GB limit will affect my program and what will happen if the size limit gets breached?

Comment: If you can't run a compact & repair to hold the size down, or split data somehow between one or more attached database (files), it will cease to operate when reaching 2 GB. It's a hard limit.

Comment: Thank you Gustav. Actually it is not happening if Access database are split and then reconnected but it is happening for sharepoint lists. Does this happen for SQL tables as well when connected as backend?

Comment: Sorry, can't tell. I've never used SP lists for a little testing, nothing serious.

Comment: No issue or problem or size increase with SQL back end tables. All data is held on the server - so no local file limit size, or growth of the front end part will occur.

Comment: @SohaibAhmedSiddiqui  Is the sharepoint cache a single table?  If it is multiple tables, can you cache it in multiple local linked database files?  Even if its currently in one table, perhaps it could be separated into multiple tables?  ... and still maintain performance gain by doing so?

Comment: Thank you Albert.

Comment: @CPerkins if I connect sharepoint table in FE, it shows as a linked table therefore I can't separate it in multiple files. If I do so, I have to make multiple FE for each task and even then it will get into trouble at some point in the future. Thing is I only know how to make procedures in Access